# Does QlikView Accept all Sql syntax?

Tags: qlikview

I am good at SQL and know nothing about QlikView. Does QlikView uses exact SQL syntax? If I create SQL scripts, will that work in QlikView or I will need to change some syntax such as DateDiff function? I am in a dilemma whether to use QlikView or Report Builder. I know Report Builder will use SQL 100%.
Please help/guide.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qlikview run SQL at it is.

Also there is some level of interaction between QV and SQL (if you want). For example having the following QV script:

```
set vDateFrom = 20140101;
set vDateTo = 20140201;

SQL
Select 
  * 
From MyTable
Where
  DateFrom >= $(vDateFrom)
and DateTo < $(vDateTo)
;
```

will result as following script being actually executed on the sql server:

```
Select 
  * 
From MyTable
Where
  DateFrom >= 20140101
and DateTo < 20140201
```

Comment: That was a great example. Thank you.